# printf, translation function and date_i18n adds extra characters

Tags: translation

So I am trying to make these strings translatable and in proper PHP/WP format. This works:

```
'Du ' . date_i18n( 'j M', strtotime( $date_debut->format('j M Y') ) ) . ' au ' . date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $date_fin->format('j M Y') ) );
```

The equivalent using `printf` should be something like this:

```
printf(
            __( 'Du %1$s au %2$s', 'my-plugin' ),
            date_i18n( 'j M', strtotime( $date_debut->format('j M Y') ) ),
            date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $date_fin->format('j M Y') ) )
    );
```

But for some reason the Year comes out as either `201914` or `201920`.

Why are there extra characters on the dates?

---

**EDIT**

The results are fine and as expected when using without the `printf()` function

```
__('Du ' . date_i18n( 'j M', strtotime( $date_de_debut ) ) . ' au ' . date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $date_de_fin ) ) );
```

Comment: What’s the result of __() function for this string? Could you var_dump it?

Comment: Good call, I’ll check on Monday!

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż thanks, I was using the wrong formatting function!

Answer (score 0):

Because the translate function `__()` worked fine, I suspected `printf()` was the culprit.

Turns out **`sprintf()`** is what I needed! `printf()` arguments [work differently](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php#example-6096)